# Can't get parameters from post in view - Django

Tags: django, django-views

I'm facing a weird problem. Suddenly I can't get data from `POST` request in my `view`. I can see that it's there.

```
@csrf_exempt
def get_candidate_prices_and_xpaths(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.POST
        request_url =  request.POST.get('request_url','')
        print request_url
```

I can see in command line this:

```
<QueryDict: {u'product_url': [u'asdasd']}>
```

and the empty line (the second `print`)

How to access the `request_url` parameter from post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using two different variables: request_url and product_url.

Comment: What a shame. I couldn't figure it out for an hour. Thank you

Comment: please consider accepting the answer if it has helped you solve the issue.

Comment: Of course, I had to wait to be able to mark it solved. Thanks